# Why do my P.L.Cs (Power line converters) devide the speed by two?

Tags: ethernet, network-speed

If I directly connect to my 100MB router with a CAT.5e cable, I get these results :

```
$ speedtest --simple 
Ping: 8.617 ms
Download: 92.54 Mbit/s
Upload: 93.90 Mbit/s
$ ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

But if I connect to my same router through two [dLAN® 200 AVmini](https://www.devolo.com/support/downloads/download/dlanr-200-avmini.html) PLCs (one power line converter connected to the router and the other to my PC), I get this :

```
$ speedtest --simple
Ping: 12.843 ms
Download: 43.86 Mbit/s
Upload: 49.06 Mbit/s
$ ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

The difference between the two is :

```
Ping: 8.617 ms                                                     |    Ping: 12.843 ms
Download: 92.54 Mbit/s                                             |    Download: 43.86 Mbit/s
Upload: 93.90 Mbit/s                                               |    Upload: 49.06 Mbit/s
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only|        Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
```

Why is the speed divided by two and how can I solve this ?

EDIT0 : One can read the [dLAN® 200 AVmini product sheet](https://www.devolo.com/fileadmin/Web-Content/DE/products/eol/dlan-200-avmini/documents/en/dev_dLAN200AVmini_productsheet_EN_05.pdf) and [HomePlug wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePlug).

Comment: There is more than one thing PLC can stand for and it's not clear which of them you're talking about. Are these programmable logic controllers? Are they power line converters? Something else entirely? If you're talking about ethernet over powerline, can you give the make and model of the devices you are using?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz They are power line converters

Comment: What's the make and model?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz [dLAN® 200 AVmini](https://www.devolo.com/support/downloads/download/dlanr-200-avmini.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your powerline converters are built to an old standard (HomePlug AV, from 2005) that doesn't provide very good performance. 50Mbps is about what you get under realistic conditions with this class of converter.

I would strongly urge you to upgrade to converters built to the newer AV2 standard from 2012. Devolo's "Magic 1 LAN" is built to the newer standard and should provide significantly better performance.

You can try plugging your converters into different outlets. Do not plug them into extension cords or power strips. You might find a configuration change that gets you some improvement.

Comment: Aren't they supposed to support 200Mbps according to [this product sheet](https://www.devolo.com/fileadmin/Web-Content/DE/Contentseiten/Downloads/Downloads_alte_Produkte/dLAN_R__200_AVmini/dev_dLAN200AVmini_productsheet_EN_05.pdf) ?

Comment: @SebMa That's the absolute maximum that you could conceivably get under perfect conditions.

Comment: @DavidSwartz They were connected to triple power outlets. I connected each of them directly to a single power outlet but still not much change. I'm going to check if they are connected to the same "power circuit" or not.

Comment: @david-swartz Both PLCs are connected to the same "electrical circuit". What can be the "perfect conditions" you have mentioned ?

Comment: @SebMa Honestly, I've never seen them. I tested PLCs about eight years ago and never got even half of the advertised speed of any non-AV2 PLC under any conditions.